# How can i convert a str into a number in python?

Tags: python, string, function, int

I would like to make my program convert `str`s into `int`s in that once that `str` is spotted at any instance python recognises it as an `int` number.

```
str('C') = 1
str('5') = 5
```

thanks

Comment: What does "is spotted at any instance" mean?

Comment: huh? why is `C` 1? and did you mean `myfun('5') = 5`?

Comment: Hmmm, why would you want to change the meaning of `str`?  Currently `str('5') = '5'` and `str('C') = 'C'`.  Changing it to do something else would really confuse your readers.

Comment: you want to `#define 'C' 1` in Python?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Python built-in `int()` function converts strings to integers:

```
>>> int('5')
5
```

However, `'C'` is not a (decimal) integer and will throw an error from `int()`:

```
>>> int('C')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'C'
```

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams: changed.

Comment: @GregHewgill; Thats the error i get exactly. so i would like to make 'C' be represented by an integer number.

Comment: @Lycon: I'm afraid I still don't understand exactly what you want. `'C'` is not a decimal integer number. How would you like to use this `C`? Could you give an example?

Comment: @GregHewgill; i want to compare lets say 'A' with '2', whereby 'A' is '1' just like in a card deck.

Comment: @Lycon: Do you just want to assign a variable? For example, `C = 1` will give the variable named `C` the value `1`.

Comment: @GregHewgill: But 'C' is a string, so how would i meke it equal to an int

Comment: Strings are not "equal to" integers. I suggest following through the [Python Tutorial](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/). Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

If you're talking about converting it to the ASCII value, it's `ord` for `char` to ASCII and `chr` for ASCII to `char`. Otherwise.. I don't know where you're getting C -> 5 from.